# How to globally configure logging for unit tests when executing them in discovery mode?

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging

Within my python package, I use the standard modules [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) to create logs, and [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) to create unit tests.

Since the files containing the unit tests are spread across the entire folder structure of the package, I use the test discovery mode to execute the unit tests:

```bash
python -m unittest discover \
       --pattern "*_test.py" \
       --start-directory "path/to/package/root"
```

Unfortunately, this results in a messed up text stream on the console because both log messages and output from the unit test runner are forwarded to `stdout`.

For single test modules (which I store in separate files `<module_name>_test.py`), I usually control the logging output globally within the `__main__`-block:

```
# In <module_name>_test.py

import logging
import unittest
# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Forward log messages into a file test.log.
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        filename="testing/output/test.log")
    unittest.main()
```

When executing `python <module_name>_test.py`, this ensures that the log messages are separated from the unit test output.

However, in test discovery mode, the `__main__`-blocks of my test-modules are never executed. Therefore my question is: How to globally set up logging in test discovery mode? Ideally, I would have to configure the logger only in a single place, and not in all test modules separately. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was relatively easy after rereading the documentation on [unittest discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) more carefully. The functionality is implemented in [`TestLoader.discover()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover).

To run all unit tests, I wrote a file `run_tests.py` that looks as follows:

```
import logging
import unittest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        filename="test.log")
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    tests = loader.discover(pattern="*_test.py",
                            start_dir="<path/to/package>")
    runner = unittest.runner.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(tests)
```